# Is there a way to define a prototype property with a reference to another property?

Tags: javascript, properties, prototype

Let's say a simple prototype is defined:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName
  this.fullName = first + " " + last;
}
```

Now, I want to add a new property down the road called `nickName`. (but I don't want to use a method, that's already well documented)

```
Person.prototype.nickName = (what to put here to have firstName + first letter of lastName)
```

I used:

```
Person.prototype = {
        get nickName(){
            return this.firstName+ this.lastName.charAt(0);
    }
};
```

But it doesn't work for already created Persons.

I just want to know if there is a way to do it, besides including it in the initial definition.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/emrczcc1/

Comment: thanks @Rayon your suggestion does work, but it must be placed before var p is declared. It seems that for an addition to work after the var is declared, one must use a method, as suggested in the answer below from Alberto Trindade.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new method to the prototype:

```
Person.prototype.nickname = function() { 
  return this.firstName + this.lastName.charAt(0); 
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Alberto. I just wanted to now if besides your solution, which uses a method, there was a way to use a property, and that the addition could be placed after instances of the object are declared.